# Transfer text from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, text

I want to transfer text from one activity to another and also need to save that text in local database. But it should ask to insert text for first time only. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One Activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(OneActivity.this, SeconActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second Activity**

```
String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```